# SliverAppBar and Listview with controller

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to have a `ListView` inside `NestedScrollView` to have `SliverAppBar` collapsed. However if I add a controller to the `ListView`, it stops working (`AppBar` does not collapse). Here's an example where left `ListView` does not affect `SliverAppBar`, but right `ListView` does.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController scrollController = new ScrollController();
  List<String> entries = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: new Scaffold(
        body: new NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              new SliverAppBar(
                  title: new Text("My app"),
                  pinned: true,
                  expandedHeight: 150.0,
                  floating: true,
                  forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                  bottom: new TabBar(
                    tabs: <Tab>[
                      new Tab(text: "FIRST"),
                      new Tab(text: "SECOND"),
                    ],
                  )),
            ];
          },
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: entries.length,
                controller: scrollController,
                itemExtent: 60.0,
                itemBuilder: (buildContext, index) {
                  return new Text(entries[index]);
                },
              ),
              new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: entries.length,
                itemExtent: 60.0,
                itemBuilder: (buildContext, index) {
                  return new Text(entries[index]);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea if it is possible to have a controller attached to a `ListView` and still notify `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: It is working fine, your scrolling focus is only shifted to the child after providing the controller, try to scroll while touching FIRST tab to see  what I mean. why do not you provide the controller to be exclusive for the parent instead ??

Comment: Oh, you are right, so basically if I have a controller, it needs to be attached to NestedScrollView instead of ListView. What if I realy wanted to attach controller to listview instead of scrollview? Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using `NestedScrollView`, you're opting in to having it manage the scroll positions of each child `Scrollable` as if it were all one unified scrollable. There isn't a way to drive the positions of individual `Scrollable` children with controllers; doing so would be challenging because it could put the `NestedScrollView` into a confused state. However, you're not totally out of luck:

- You can give a controller to the `NestedScrollView`.
- If you just want to be notified about the current scroll position or update when there are scroll events in the nested scroll views, you can wrap the `Scrollable` in a [`NotificationListener`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html) to listen for [`ScrollNotification`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html).
- If you want to make a child `Scrollable` "reset" to a zero initial scroll position, you could change its `key` to blow away its state.

Comment: Yes, according to @aziza answer I moved controller to NestedScrollView

Comment: Yeah I was responding to your follow up question. I’ve edited my answer to mention that.