# How to use ListView and fetch data at the same time in flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, rest, flutter-listview

I am working on a **flutter application** where I want to implement the following functionality-
Using a **REST API** (from Spring Boot backend server), fetch the data from the internet and show it in a list view. Now, we can use multiple approaches here-

1. **Fetch all the data at once** using a **single call to the REST API** and then create listview with all the data fetched (say 100 items) **(using ListView.builder)**.
2. Fetch **some data at once (say 10 items)**, create the list view with it and while the user scrolls through that list, fetch the next items of the list and add them to the list **(Use a loading indicator at the end of list to show that data is being loaded. (like we generally see on Social Media apps or News apps)**

I know, how to fetch all the data at once, but now **I want to use the second approach.** Can somebody explain how this can be achieved?

Comment: You need use pagination to achieve the second problem. You need to pass per_page & page_number while fetching API , the keys may vary based on your api implementation. ONCE YOU ARE DONE WITH THIS, attach a scrollcontroller to listview and a listener to thaat scrollcontroller . if controller is scrolled to max extent, call again API by updating page number and populate the data

Comment: https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-listview-pagination-load-more/

Comment: Could you solve your problem with the provided material?

Comment: @ManishDayma I referred https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-listview-pagination-load-more/  Can you tell what should I do if there are some preceding widgets before listview on the page? How to decide the extent then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you are describing in your question is commonly referred to as [Lazy Loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading).

To have a lazy loading functionality inside a flutter `ListView` there are probably two main approaches you could take.

You could for example use a predefined package with does that for you and is configurable like [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination)

Otherwise you can also write a lazy loading functionality by yourself. This depends mainly on your usecases and preferences. I'll briefly summarize how that would work.

Your `ListView` can have a [ScrollController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition-class.html). As you can see in the documentation it is possible to find out the current [scroll position](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition-class.html) of the `ListView` with this controller.

You can add a listener to your `scrollController` and if the scroll position exceeds a certain threshold you simply fire request to your server which response then populates your list.

A listener could be a simple function for example:

```
scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);

void _scrollListener() {
    if (controller.position.extentAfter < 500) {
      // Send your request
      // State change for loading animation
      // State change and add server response to your list
  }
}
```

As you can see the crucial point in that case is the `extentAfter`. This indicates that our remaining scroll space is lower than `500` therefore we want to trigger a server request to further populate our `ListView`.

Remember to remove your listener in case you `dispose` you widget.

---

If you do not want to use a `ScrollController` you could also use a [ScrollNotification](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html) and a [NotificationListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html). You can read more about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035594/flutter-notificationlistener-with-scrollnotification-vs-scrollcontroller) or in the [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html). To give a small example:

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: // your dynamic item count
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      // return Your items
    },
  ),
  onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
    if (scrollInfo.metrics.extentAfter < 500) {
      // Do your lazy loading stuff
    }
  },
);
```

What approach you want to take basically depends on you and your needs.